# matplotlib pie charts leave labels from previous pie chart

Tags: python, django, charts, matplotlib

I have a small Django app that produces two different pie charts.
But the labels from the first chart that's displayed reappear in
the second chart.

I'm just using:

```
plt.pie(...)
plt.savefig(...)
```

In the same view for two different pie charts using two different
(small) datasets.

Is there some 'clear' or 'reset' method I need to call after the saving of the
plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave your code unchanged, and clean your figure by calling `clf()` after having saved the first plot and before generating the second plot.

By doing so, you are interfacing with `matplotlib` state-machine. Matplotlib automatically creates figure and axes for you, and you use keep using the same figure.

The alternative is to use `matplotlib` in a more object-oriented way. You ask matplotlib to create figure and axes object, and then you do all the rest by calling methods of those objects:

```
fig1,ax1=plt.subplots()
fig2,ax2=plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(...)
ax2.pie(...)
fig1.savefig(...)
fig2.savefig(...)
```

The usage FAQ [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html) clarifies the two options.

Comment: I stopped too soon; 'clear()' is a synonym for 'clf()' for the Figure object but not for the matplotlib.pyplot object. I tried 'clear()' but not 'clf()'. Thanks!